# Comparison test for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^5 + n^3 - n}}{2n^3 + 3n^2 + 1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to use comparison test to show that this series diverges:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^5 + n^3 - n}}{2n^3 + 3n^2 + 1}$$

Here are the steps I have come up with but I am not sure if it is right.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^5}}{3n^3}\ \text{diverges (by integral test)}$$

$$0 < \frac{\sqrt{n^5}}{3n^3} \leq a_n\ \text{(for large n)}$$

$$\therefore a_n\ \text{diverges}$$

Note: I added "for large n" since according to Wolfram|Alpha, it is only true for n > 2.671... is this permissible or does it mean I have made an error?

Comment: You didn't prove the inequality.

Comment: Saying for $n>2$ is enough. To prove convergence/divergence, you needn't worry about the first terms (finite number).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt{n^5 + n^3 - n}}{2n^3 + 3n^2 + 1}\ge\frac{\sqrt{n^5}}{2n^3+2n^3+2n^3}=\frac{n^{5/2}}{6n^3}=\frac16\frac1{\sqrt n}$$

and since $\;\sum\frac1{\sqrt n}\;$ diverges ...

Comment: I would have gone $2n^3+3n^2+1\le 2n^3+3n^3+n^3=6n^3$ for the denominator, with same result, but I don't really follow the $2,2,2$ coefficients, is that typo ?

Comment: @zwim Both results, yours and mine are correct because of the power of $\;n\;$, aren't they? I just wanted to write down a very easy expression, that's all.

Answer (score 3):

It is much simpler to use this result from *asymptotic analysis*:

> Let $\sum_n u_n$ and $\sum_n v_n$ two  series with (ultimately) positive terms, such that $u_n\sim_\infty v_n$. Then $\sum _n u_n$ and $\sum_n v_n$ both converge or both diverge.

Now a polynomial is asymptotically equivalent to its leading term, so
$$\frac{\sqrt{n^5 + n^3 - n}}{2n^3 + 3n^2 + 1}\sim_\infty\frac{\sqrt{n^5}}{2n^3}=\frac 1{2\sqrt n},$$
and the latter is a divergent $p$-series.

Comment: In the theorem cited, we need to have absolute cv, i.e. $u_n,\ v_n\ge 0$ (or of constant sign).

Comment: This is the case if $n$ is large enough – it is an asymptotic comparison.

Comment: Yes, but since you cite verbatim a theorem, the wording has to be correct. OP is not supposed to guess. I have seen many students here applying it for alternated series...

Comment: Agreed. I've added a more complete wording.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is permissible, and instead of worrying about a direct comparison you should use the *limit comparison test*: since
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\dfrac{\sqrt{n^5+n^3-n}}{2n^3 + 3n^2 + 1}}{\dfrac{\sqrt{n^5}}{2n^3}} = 1$$
the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\sqrt{n^5+n^3-n}}{2n^3 + 3n^2 + 1} \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\sqrt{n^5}}{2n^3}$$ either both converge or both diverge.